# Checking for files that are mentioned as children of other files

Tags: javascript, comparative-review, ecmascript-6, grunt.js

I am working in JavaScript on a GruntFile script, and I am creating an object that holds a file class for each one of the following class structure:

```
class file = {
    path: string,
    name: string,
    children: string[],
    parents: string[],
    packages: string[]
}
```

I need to loop over each one of these files in the object, and for each one of the files loop over all of the *other* files and check if their `children` array contains the current file matching on `name`.

My coworker and I have come up with multiple solutions to this nasty business.

The first is a more "streamlined" approach, which is believed to "execute faster":

```
const fileArray = Object.keys(files).map( key => files[key]);
fileArray.forEach( fileOuter => fileArray.forEach( fileInner => { if ( fileInner.children.includes(fileOuter.name)) fileOuter.parents.push(fileInner.name) } ) );
```

The second solution is clearer:

```
// Loop over all files by key
Object.keys( files ).forEach( key => {

    // Get the current file name
    const curFileName = file.name;

    // Loop over all files again
    Object.keys(files).forEach( innerKey => {

        // Get the inner loop file
        const fileInner = files[innerKey];

        // If the file lists the current file as a dependency
        if ( fileInner.children.indexOf(curFileName) !== -1 ){

            // Push the file name into the parents array for the current file
            files[curFileName].parents.push(fileInner.name);
        }
    })
})
```

Or if we really wanted to make the loop as fast as possible:

```
// Get the object keys of the files object
const fileKeys = Object.keys(files);

// Loop over each file
for( var i=0, j=fileKeys.length; i<j; i++){

    // Get the current file name
    const curFileName = files[fileKeys[i]].name;

    // Loop over each file
    for( k=0, k<j, k++){

        // Get the inner file
        const fileInner = files[fileKeys[k]];

        // If the inner files children array matches the current file name, push the inner file name to the current files parents array
        if( fileInner.children.indexOf(curFileName) !== 1 ) files[curFileName].parents.push( fileInner.name );
    }
}
```

Is any of these methods objectively better than the other? Is there an even *better* approach we could be taking for this task?

Comment: if you want to compare two methods of doing something on codereview don't post "my way" vs "my coworker's way" because it always makes it sound like you're trying to settle a bet or say "i told you so." just show the two different ways to do it and ask for feedback. we don't need to know about a dispute between you and your co-worker.

Comment: also, both ways are programmatic. perhaps you meant procedural (even tho the example you posted is functional, not procedural). i vote for your co-worker's way. it's more concise. and why on earth are you worried about speed in your gruntfile anyway, who cares how fast the build script is.

Comment: Did you downvote this because of something you read into? My team mate and I are leading the charge for coding standards for our team, and trying to decide together which way we encourage our team to develop.  This has nothing to do with rivalry.

Comment: I explained in my comments why I voted. if you care to adjust your question I will adjust my vote

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce Edited for neutrality in Rev 2.

Comment: Hard to do a review when all 3 examples have different results. Maybe you should fix the bugs first. Second example outer loop should be `curFileName = files[key].name;` Third example, has undeclared `k` and the `indexOf(?) !== 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General Remarks

- Why are your files assigned to properties of an object? Keeping them in an array would be simpler. Or do you wish to store some kind of mapping from id → file? You currently use the file's name as a unique id which would then redundantly appear on both sides of that mapping.
- Matching only by file name seems risky to me, but it really depends on your definition of 'child'. Depending on the exact use case, a file path plus name or a file hash value might be a more suitable unique identifier.
- I would avoid talking about 'class structure' when describing the structure of anonymous objects. 'class' has a specific meaning, especially since the class keyword has been introduced to JavaScript now. If your files were really instances of a class, you would probably want to use some kind of creational design pattern such as a factory or factory method which avoids the issue of having to deal with incompletely initialized instances until you finally fill in the parents.

### Style

- The first code sample could be more readable if it weren't squeezed into a single line.
- All code samples could benefit from better naming. Instead of `file` write `child`, instead of `fileInner` write `parent`, instead of `curFileName` write `child.name` etc.
- Instead of `indexOf` use `includes`. Since you already use `const`, you should also use `let` instead of `var` or globals.
- Instead of `Object.keys` use `Object.values`.

Your first or second example could be written as:

```
files.forEach(parent => {
  files.forEach(child => {
    if (parent.children.includes(child.name)) {
      child.parents.push(parent.name);
    }
  });
})
```

Alternatively using for-of-loops:

```
for (const child of files) {
  for (const parent of files) {
    if (parent.children.includes(child.name)) {
      child.parents.push(parent.name);
    }
  }
}
```

If `files` is not an array but an object, replace `files` with `Object.values(files)`.

### Performance

If performance is really an issue, look into the runtime complexity of your operations. By introducing an explicit `Map` from parent names to children files, the runtime complexity could be reduced to depend linearly on the total number of children only.

Comment: The files are stored an object so that they can be referenced by name quickly, it is essentially being used as a dictionary of files.  There is a lot of cross-referencing and tree navigation going on behind the scenes to find child and parent dependencies and being able to say `files[fileName]` is better than having to loop over the entire array to find the one I need every time I need a reference.

Comment: That's a valid point. Still, don't you have to deal with file name collisions, i.e. files with identical names in different directories?

Comment: Thankfully no. I am dealing with a library of Angular 4 components and modules, thus unique names are required.